# How to add a header to an existing csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I know this is a very basic question.
I have a CSV file, which contains data already. This file is generated automatically not using opening with `Dictreader` or open object.

### Goal

1. I want to open an existing file
2. Append the Header in the first row (Shift the first row data)
3. Save the file
4. Return the file

Any clues?

```
cursor.execute(sql, params + (csv_path,))
```

This command generates file, without header.

### Code

```
  sql, params = queryset.query.sql_with_params()
    sql += ''' INTO OUTFILE %s
           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' '''
    csv_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\tmp', csv_filename)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(sql, params + (csv_path,))
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description] #error
```

### Tried

```
SELECT `website` UNION SELECT `request_system_potentialcustomers`.`website` FROM `request_system_potentialcustomers` ORDER BY `request_system_potentialcustomers`.`revenue` DESC  
INTO OUTFILE "D:\\out.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: `cat file >> header`

Comment: @Vor - not only is that not in python (it's using a linux CLI), but it appends content to the end of a file - not the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean by CAT file >> header? I want to use it in python

Comment: You need to shift the first row, and write your header there. But whats the code?

Comment: The SQL code is irrelevant to the actual question, and can be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait a minute. If you have not yet called

```
cursor.execute(sql, params + (csv_path,))
```

then you have the opportunity to write the CSV file correctly from the get-go. You should not need to write a new file with the header line, then copy all that CSV into the new file and so forth. That is slow and inefficient -- and your only choice -- **if** you really have to prepend a line to an existing file.

If instead you have not yet written the CSV file, and if you know the `header`, then you can add it to the SQL using `SELECT ... UNION ... SELECT`:

```
header = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', ]
query = ['SELECT {} UNION'.format(','.join([repr(h) for h in header]))]
sql, params = queryset.query.sql_with_params()
query.append(sql)
sql = '''INTO OUTFILE %s
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
         OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' '''
query.append(sql)
sql = ' '.join(query)         
csv_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\tmp', csv_filename)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, params + (csv_path,))
```

---

Demo:

```
mysql> SELECT "foo", "bar" UNION SELECT "baz", "quux" INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/out";
```

Produces the file `/tmp/out` containing

```
foo bar
baz quux
```

Comment: Its giving error of unknown colomn in field list, Check update of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong type of quotes. Don't use backticks; use double-quotes for the *literal* header names: `SELECT "website" UNION ...`. (Use backticks if necessary for column names.)

Comment: Adding backits worked for me. Thank you so much, That was really genius way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[`Cursor.description` attribute](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) give you information about the result column.

```
cursor.execute(sql, params + (csv_path,))
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
```

1. Write above information to the new file.
2. Append old csv contents to the new file.
3. Rename the new file with the old file name.

Comment: columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @Jack, Make sure you called `execute` with `SELECT ..` statement before you access `description` attribute.

Comment: Code added. please check it.

Comment: @Jack, Please try without `INTO ...` part.

Comment: I need to use `INTO` cuz i want to stream this big csv to the response.

Comment: @Jack, I mean only for the header (preferably with `LIMIT 0`).

Comment: Could you please write the algo which is easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear if you are trying to read an existing csv file or not, but to read a csv off disk without column names:

Use dictreader/dictwriter and specify the column names in your file

Python 3:

```
import csv
ordered_filenames = ['animal','height','weight']

with open('stuff.csv') as csvfile, open("result.csv","w",newline='') as result:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=ordered_filenames)
    wtr = csv.DictWriter(result, ordered_filenames)
    wtr.writeheader()
    for line in rdr:
        wtr.writerow(line)
```

With stuff.csv in the same directory:

```
elephant,1,200
cat,0.1,1
dog,0.2,2
```

and the output result file:

```
animal,height,weight
elephant,1,200
cat,0.1,1
dog,0.2,2
```